# git-lfs: command not found

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Here is my GitLab stage with script:-

```
stages:
  - lfs

lfs:
  stage: lfs
  image: python:3.9
  script:
    - echo "running lfs clean up"
    - git --version
    - python --version
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip3 install git-lfs
```

As per the Job's log, the git-lfs is installed but when I try to print the version, it says command not found. Here is log reference:-

```
$ git --version
git version 2.39.2
$ python --version
Python 3.9.18
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 24.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
Successfully installed pip-23.2.1
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
$ pip3 install git-lfs
Collecting git-lfs
  Downloading git_lfs-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Installing collected packages: git-lfs
Successfully installed git-lfs-1.6
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
$ git-lfs --version
/usr/bin/bash: line 142: git-lfs: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: `pip install git-lfs` doesn't install `git-lfs`. It installs https://pypi.org/project/git-lfs/ "*This module cannot fully replace the official git-lfs client, it only knows how to download the files, cache them (the same way the official client does), and place them in a checkout directory. Uploading files is not implemented at all.*"

Comment: See https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs?#installing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [library you installed](https://github.com/liberapay/git-lfs-fetch.py) does not have any [entrypoints](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#entry-points), as such you cannot use it from the terminal like that.

Instead, you must use:

```bash
$ python3 -m git_lfs
```

---

I suspect however you most likely don't want to do this though, and you actually want `git-lfs`. To install that in `python:3.9` container, then you can use:

```bash
$ apt-get update -y; apt-get upgrade -y
$ apt-get install git-lfs
$ git-lfs --version
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.19.8)
```